# Trash icon incorrect after removing removeable media

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, trash

On a USB drive, if I move files to trash, the trash icon changes from empty to full, as it should.

However, if I then remove the USB drive (without emptying the trash), the trash icon still shows trash in it.
The only way I could get the icon back to empty is to reconnect the drive and then empty the trash.

Normally this is OK but on one case the USB drive with trash files was formatted, so now there is nothing left to empty. The trash icon still is full one, even though Trash folder is empty.
What I see:
[image]

[image]

Is this icon display related to removable drives normal? It seems counter-intuitive.

And now, how to remove the yellow bar/empty button, or where is it controlled?

Comment: Formatting the drive probably gave it a new UUID, so the OS thinks it is a different drive.  If that is the case, maybe the icon will reset after you reboot the system.

Comment: @StephenDaddona You are correct. Rebooting reset the icon. The problem itself wasn't the local trash, but the usb drive's trash, which showed 1 file. And somehow that drive became read only (per dmesg | tail) so couldn't be deleted. I copied over the contents and then formatted it. Then it's operation was normal again. The OS in some manner must track drive status by UUID, and any change becomes a new drive. I'd be interested in the actual mechanism involved.

Comment: I think the system does track by UUID.  I have two, identical, USB memory sticks and all of the computers that I have plugged them into can tell them apart from each other even if they have identical data on them.

Comment: @StephenDaddona Also if you could include where this tracking happens...

Answer (score 1):

When you delete files on an external storage media device, such as a USB drive, and then remove the drive without emptying the trash, the trash icon may show items still in the trash.

If you reformat that external drive, it will get a new UUID and, when you mount it again, it will appear to be a different drive.  So the OS will not know that it is the same drive and will not be able to clear the trash icon.

Rebooting the system with the USB drive removed will probably clear the trash icon.

I do not know where this tracking information is stored in Ubuntu.